# What is the best approximation, in the inf-norm on the interval $[-1,1]$, of $\cosh(x)$ by a quadratic polynomial?

Tags: optimization, numerical-methods, normed-spaces, approximation

I am studying for an examination and this is a problem from a few years back:

> What is the best approximation, in the inf-norm on the interval $[-1,1]$, of $\cosh(x)$ by a quadratic polynomial?

Any tips or direction would be great!

Comment: Chebyshev approximation.

Comment: What is inf-norm?

Comment: the inf norm is the max difference over the interval between the two functions. A.K.A. The infinity norm for functions.